# Access UNION Query Crashes Access

Tags: sql, ms-access, join, union

I have a billing system that generates 2 set of invoice queries (qInvoicesAutomatic and qInvoicesManual). I have two queries built from Unions of both invoice queries, one which counts the amount of invoice records, and a second that calculates the total of their entire bill. Both of which I can run successfully(returning equal number of records), code below for each:

qUniqueInvoices

```
SELECT DISTINCT qInvoicesAutomatic.APN AS APN
    ,qInvoicesAutomatic.PeriodID AS PeriodID
    ,count(*) AS InvoiceRecords
    ,(qInvoicesAutomatic.APN & qInvoicesAutomatic.PeriodID) AS PrimKey
FROM qInvoicesAutomatic
GROUP BY qInvoicesAutomatic.APN
    ,qInvoicesAutomatic.PeriodID
    ,(qInvoicesAutomatic.APN & qInvoicesAutomatic.PeriodID)

UNION

SELECT DISTINCT qInvoicesManual.APN AS APN
    ,qInvoicesManual.PeriodID AS PeriodID
    ,count(*) AS InvoiceRecords
    ,(APN & PeriodID) AS PrimKey
FROM qInvoicesManual
GROUP BY qInvoicesManual.APN
    ,qInvoicesManual.PeriodID
    ,(APN & PeriodID);
```

qUniqueTotals

```
SELECT DISTINCT qInvoiceBasechargeAUTO.APN
    ,qInvoiceBasechargeAUTO.PeriodID
    ,Sum(qInvoiceBasechargeAUTO.TotalBaseCharge) AS TotalAnnualBaseCharge
    ,qInvoiceUsageAUTO.TotalVariableCharge
    ,(Sum(qInvoiceBasechargeAUTO.TotalBaseCharge) + (qInvoiceUsageAUTO.TotalVariableCharge) - (qinvoiceUsageAUTO.CAREUsageDiscount) - Sum(qInvoiceBasechargeAUTO.CAREBasechargeDiscount)) AS TotalAnnual
    ,qinvoiceUsageAUTO.CAREUsageDiscount
    ,Sum(qInvoiceBasechargeAUTO.CAREBasechargeDiscount) AS TotalCAREBaseChargeDiscount
    ,(qInvoiceBasechargeAUTO.APN & qInvoiceBasechargeAUTO.PeriodID) AS PrimKey
FROM qInvoiceBasechargeAUTO
INNER JOIN qInvoiceUsageAUTO ON qInvoiceBasechargeAUTO.APN = qInvoiceUsageAUTO.APN
WHERE (((qInvoiceBasechargeAUTO.PeriodID) = [qInvoiceUsageAUTO].[PeriodID]))
GROUP BY qInvoiceBasechargeAUTO.APN
    ,qInvoiceBasechargeAUTO.PeriodID
    ,qInvoiceUsageAUTO.TotalVariableCharge
    ,qInvoiceUsageAUTO.CAREUsageDiscount
    ,(qInvoiceBasechargeAUTO.APN & qInvoiceBasechargeAUTO.PeriodID)

UNION

SELECT DISTINCT APN
    ,PeriodID
    ,Sum(TotalBaseCharge) AS TotalAnnualBaseCharge
    ,TotalVariableCharge
    ,(Sum(TotalBaseCharge) + TotalVariableCharge - CAREUsageDiscount - Sum(CAREBaseChargeDiscount)) AS TotalAnnual
    ,(APN & PeriodID) AS PrimKey
    ,CAREUsageDiscount
    ,Sum(CAREBaseChargeDiscount) AS TotalCAREBaseChargeDiscount
FROM qInvoicesManual
GROUP BY APN
    ,Periodid
    ,TotalVariableCharge
    ,CAREUsageDiscount
    ,(APN & PeriodID);
```

I then join qUniqueInvoices and qUniqueTotals on the PrimKey in qUniqueBills to get the info regarding each bill (number of invoice records, and total information). Query below:

qUniqueBills

```
SELECT qUniqueInvoices.APN
    ,qUniqueInvoices.PeriodID
    ,qUniqueInvoices.InvoiceRecords
    ,qUniqueTotals.TotalAnnual
FROM qUniqueInvoices
LEFT JOIN qUniqueTotals ON qUniqueInvoices.PrimKey = qUniqueTotals.PrimKey
ORDER BY qUniqueInvoices.APN
    ,qUniqueInvoices.PeriodID;
```

My issue is that is that when I try to filter qUniqueBills in a datasheet form it either crashes Access, or it returns that there is an unequal amount of rows in the union query, or it says enter a valid value. Just to reiterate, all of the above queries work individually when run. I've tried repairing the database. Is there a better way to join my invoice data, which contains identical data sets?

Comment: Update: I fixed all my lazy references so that they include table names as well(still too lazy to reupload code as it doesnt affect anything). Re-ran the queries, in reverse order, all worked until qUniqueInvoices when I tried to filter it said unequal columns in join, I then re-ran the filter and it worked. Re-ran it and it crashed access.. ????

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem in the second query  (quniqeTotals) the fields in the both  select  in the union must be matched.
So the right is

```
SELECT DISTINCT qInvoiceBasechargeAUTO.APN
,qInvoiceBasechargeAUTO.PeriodID
,Sum(qInvoiceBasechargeAUTO.TotalBaseCharge) AS TotalAnnualBaseCharge
,qInvoiceUsageAUTO.TotalVariableCharge
,(Sum(qInvoiceBasechargeAUTO.TotalBaseCharge) + (qInvoiceUsageAUTO.TotalVariableCharge) - (qinvoiceUsageAUTO.CAREUsageDiscount) - Sum(qInvoiceBasechargeAUTO.CAREBasechargeDiscount)) AS TotalAnnual
,qinvoiceUsageAUTO.CAREUsageDiscount
,Sum(qInvoiceBasechargeAUTO.CAREBasechargeDiscount) AS TotalCAREBaseChargeDiscount
,(qInvoiceBasechargeAUTO.APN & qInvoiceBasechargeAUTO.PeriodID) AS PrimKey
FROM qInvoiceBasechargeAUTO
INNER JOIN qInvoiceUsageAUTO ON qInvoiceBasechargeAUTO.APN = qInvoiceUsageAUTO.APN
WHERE (((qInvoiceBasechargeAUTO.PeriodID) = [qInvoiceUsageAUTO].[PeriodID]))
GROUP BY qInvoiceBasechargeAUTO.APN
,qInvoiceBasechargeAUTO.PeriodID
,qInvoiceUsageAUTO.TotalVariableCharge
,qInvoiceUsageAUTO.CAREUsageDiscount
,(qInvoiceBasechargeAUTO.APN & qInvoiceBasechargeAUTO.PeriodID)

UNION

SELECT DISTINCT APN
,PeriodID
,Sum(TotalBaseCharge) AS TotalAnnualBaseCharge
,TotalVariableCharge
,(Sum(TotalBaseCharge) + TotalVariableCharge - CAREUsageDiscount - Sum(CAREBaseChargeDiscount)) AS TotalAnnual
,CAREUsageDiscount
,Sum(CAREBaseChargeDiscount) AS TotalCAREBaseChargeDiscount
 ,(APN & PeriodID) AS PrimKey
FROM qInvoicesManual
GROUP BY APN
,Periodid
,TotalVariableCharge
,CAREUsageDiscount
,(APN & PeriodID);
```

Comment: "fields in the both select in the union must be matched." Indeed.

Comment: Tried rearranging the order so theyre identical. Didnt fix anything. Im actually having the problems with qUniqueInvoices.